# Как можно решать ряды подобного типа?

Tags: c#

Есть вот такой ряд, каким образом в цикле можно добавлять блоки (a + 1) к знаменателю в формуле?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
double result = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    result += factorial(i) / Math.Pow(a, i + 1);
}
```

Этот код подходит только для первой части этой серии, как при следующей итерации я могу добавить в формулу блок (a + 1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поделите i-ое слагаемое на (i-1)-ое, получится

```
d_i = i!/ ((i-1)! a (a + 1) ... (a + i - 1)) = i/(a (a + 1) ... (a + i - 1))
```

для i >= 1.

Имея первое слагаемое и зная `d_i`, можно последовательно вычислять следующие слагаемые и накапливать сумму.

Теперь, как подсчитать `d_i`? Числитель у нас есть, а на знаменатель `h_i = a (a + 1) ... (a + i - 1)` можно составить аналогичное итеративное соотношение:

```
h_i / h_(i-1) = a + i - 1
```

для i >= 2.

Таким образом, на каждом шаге находите `h_i`, потом `d_i`, потом текущее слагаемое.

Код не даю, поскольку это явно учебное задание.